# UnsupportedOperationException The "android" command is no longer included in the SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, build-tools

I have project in `Kotlin` and I have updated Android Studio to 2.3.3 and `gradle` to 3.3 and build tools to 25.3.1. During building I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The "android" command is no longer included in the SDK. Any references to it (e.g. by third-party plugins) should be removed.
        at com.android.SdkConstants.androidCmdName(SdkConstants.java:1947)
        at com.android.SdkConstants$androidCmdName$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.AndroidCommand$Real.<init>(AndroidCommand.groovy:21)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.PackageResolver.resolve(PackageResolver.groovy:22)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.PackageResolver$resolve.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin$_apply_closure2$_closure3.doCall(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy:44)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin$_apply_closure2$_closure3.doCall(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin.time(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy:51)
        at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin$_apply_closure2.doCall(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy:43)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
        ... 56 more
```

Gralde file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:master'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

task increaseBuildStageVersion << {
    def versionPropsFileI = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFileI.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionPropsI = new Properties()

        versionPropsI.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFileI))
        def value = 1
        println("INCREASING STAGE VERSION")

        def versionBuild = versionPropsI['VERSION_BUILD_STAGE'].toInteger() + value
        def codeVersion = versionPropsI['VERSION_CODE_STAGE'].toInteger() + value

        versionPropsI['VERSION_BUILD_STAGE'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionPropsI['VERSION_CODE_STAGE'] = codeVersion.toString()

        versionPropsI.store(versionPropsFileI.newWriter(), null)
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
}

task increaseBuildProductionVersion << {
    def versionPropsFileI = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFileI.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionPropsI = new Properties()

        versionPropsI.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFileI))
        def value = 1
        println("INCREASING PRODUCTION VERSION")

        def versionBuild = versionPropsI['VERSION_BUILD_PRODUCTION'].toInteger() + value
        def codeVersion = versionPropsI['VERSION_CODE_PRODUCTION'].toInteger() + value

        versionPropsI['VERSION_BUILD_PRODUCTION'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionPropsI['VERSION_CODE_PRODUCTION'] = codeVersion.toString()

        versionPropsI.store(versionPropsFileI.newWriter(), null)
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'packageStageRelease') {
        task.dependsOn increaseBuildStageVersion
    } else if (task.name == 'packageProductionRelease') {
        task.dependsOn increaseBuildProductionVersion
    }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            .....
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fivedottwelve.bonusapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release


            def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
            def buildTime = new GregorianCalendar().format("dd-MM-yyyy' 'h:mm:ss a Z")
            buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"{$gitSha}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"{$buildTime}\""
        }

        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true

            buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"DEBUG\""
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"BUILD_TIME\""
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        development {
            versionName "1.0." + getStageVersionName() + "-stage"
            versionCode getStageVersionCode()
            applicationIdSuffix ".stage"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "BonusApp"

            buildConfigField('String', 'API_URL', "\"https://fivedottwelve.com/\"")
        }
        stage {
            versionName "1.0." + getStageVersionName() + "-stage"
            versionCode getStageVersionCode()
            applicationIdSuffix ".stage"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "BonusApp"

            buildConfigField('String', 'API_URL', "\"https://fivedottwelve.com/\"")

        }
        production {
            versionName "1.0." + getProdVersionName()
            versionCode getProdVersionCode()
            resValue "string", "app_name", "BonusApp"

            buildConfigField('String', 'API_URL', "\"https://fivedottwelve.com/\"")
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        maxProcessCount 6
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            // All the usual Gradle options.
            testLogging {
                jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
                outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
                showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage', 'ContentDescription'
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    compile 'com.github.salomonbrys.kotson:kotson:2.5.0'

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.ext.android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.ext.android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.ext.android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.ext.android_support_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$rootProject.ext.play_service_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.ext.play_service_version"

    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.Dagger_version"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.ext.Dagger_version"

    compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:$rootProject.ext.RxJava_version"
    compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$rootProject.ext.RxAndroid_version"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'


    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.ext.retrofit_http_version"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$rootProject.ext.retrofit_http_version"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.ext.retrofit_http_version"

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.ext.retorfit_version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.ext.retorfit_version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$rootProject.ext.retorfit_version"

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'

    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'

    //glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'

    //transitions
    compile "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.0"

    //beacons
    compile "com.kontaktio:sdk:$rootProject.ext.kontakt_io"

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.livotovlabs.pro/content/groups/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

/*
Resolves dependency versions across test and production APKs, specifically, transitive
dependencies. This is required since Espresso internally has a dependency on support-annotations.
*/
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.ext.android_support_version"
}

/*
All direct/transitive dependencies shared between your test and production APKs need to be
excluded from the test APK! This is necessary because both APKs will contain the same classes. Not
excluding these dependencies from your test configuration will result in an dex pre-verifier error
at runtime. More info in this tools bug: (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192497)
*/
configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed `apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'` and it works

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed `apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'` and it works

Comment: i really appricate you!
By the way, what does ```apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'```  means ?

Comment: @Hajime more info here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin